# Using for a hashtable value the name of a method?

Tags: java, methods, hashtable

I have created a hash table that will keep as a key a string that will represent the name of the method that the user will give, and as value the actual method call, as string too. The code I am using is the one here:

```
public void getMethod(String givenMethod){

    Map<String, String> methods = new HashMap<String, String>();
    methods.put("length", "length();");

    methods.get(givenMethod);

}
```

From the main method I call objectX.getMethod("length");, but the method length(); is not executed. Can someone help me please?

Comment: What makes you think converting a method name into a string, adding parantheses and then accessing that string by getting it from a map would cause execution of that method? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: You need to be using Java's reflection API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Java **reflection to call method by its name 
(as you said you are storing method name in map).
For more detail read following article :
http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/

Answer (score 3):

You are getting the method but you are not invoking it. You'll have to do something like this:

```
Method yourMethod = objectX.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("yourMethodName"); //This is the string that represents the name of the method.
```

Then you invoke the method. All this through reflection:

```
yourMethod.invoke(YourObject);
```

The parameter of the invoke method is first the object, and then the attributes.

You can also get the return type of the method and cast the result, since the invoking the method will result in an Object type method:

```
yourMethod.getReturnType(); //This line gives you the type returned by your method.
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use reflection to call a method by name.  So your data structure would look more like

```
Map<String, Method> meth = new Hashmap<String,Method>();
```

Where [Method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html) is an actual object.

Comment: Perhaps you should  give a usage example.